# How to display contact name while dialing the call in android programmatically

Tags: android, phone-call, dialing

I can't display the contact name while dialing a call in Android.

**Here is my code:**

```
String callTo = "9999900000";
String callername="xxx";    
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                 
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+ callTo));                  
String srvname=Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE;    
TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(srvname);                     
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Comment: This is a fundamental problem with your understanding of how Intent works.

Answer (score 1):

For that you need to create a broadcast receiver and in *OnReceive* method check an `OUTGOING CALL` state and then get caller number from that and then create another method to check whether the contact exists in you mobile or not for that pass that contact number in the method.

Below is the code for Caller name broadcastReceiver

```
package com.example.user.caller;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;


import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.widget.Toast;



/**
 * Created by Vinod Dirishala on 11/27/2016.
 */
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    String phoneNumber;
    String name;



    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action=intent.getAction();
        Bundle extras=intent.getExtras();
        if(action.equals("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")){
            String state=extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){

                String incomingnumber=extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                String msg = "";
                //  String person = getCname(context,msg);

                String names = getContactDisplayNameByNumber(incomingnumber,context);

                //  Toast.makeText(context,"Caller Name"+person,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                displayToast(context,"phone is ringing"+incomingnumber+ "calling you mr."+names);

                Intent intent1  = new Intent(context,
                        MainActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("contactname", names);  //<<< put sms text
                context.startActivity(intent);
                //  displayToast(context,"phone is ringing"+person);
                // displayToast(context,"Vinod your  phone is ringing"+contacname);
            }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"phone in idle",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
                Toast.makeText(context,"phone in offhook",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else if(action.equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")){

            displayToast(context,"SMS Recived");
        }
    }




    private void displayToast(Context context,String msg){
        Toast.makeText(context,msg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public String getCname(Context context,String name)
    {
        ContentResolver cr=context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
            name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            System.out.println(" Phone Nuber.................."+phoneNumber);
            //  aa.add(name);
            // aa.add(phoneNumber);

        }
        return name;
    }

    public String getContactDisplayNameByNumber(String number,Context context) {
        Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number));
        name = "Incoming call from";

        ContentResolver contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor contactLookup = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);

        try {
            if (contactLookup != null && contactLookup.getCount() > 0) {
                contactLookup.moveToNext();
                name = contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // this.id =
                // contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID));
                // String contactId =
                // contactLookup.getString(contactLookup.getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
            }else{
                name = "Unknown number";
            }
        } finally {
            if (contactLookup != null) {
                contactLookup.close();
            }
        }

        return name;
    }


}
```

to download code visit this [link](https://github.com/VinodDirishala/AndroidApplicationDevelopment/blob/master/Caller.zip)  done by Vinod Dirishala

Comment: if "name" is member variable, why are you even bothering to return it.